# Can a Class clone property from a different class other than the parent class

Tags: c#, .net

I have been working on a problem in MVC where I was facing code duplicity issue creating View-Models. I was wondering if there is a way to create a class whose properties can refer to properties defined in another class. I just need to write the property name or just the reference. I basically need all other stuff like Annotations should automatically come over to my new class definition.

Here is what I am looking for:

let say I have a Class A having some annotations.

```
Class A {

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email ID")]
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        [Required]

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string FName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to write a new class B referring to some properties defined in class A.

```
Class B {
    public string EmailID; //should refer to class B so that I don't have to write annotations again
    public string newproperty;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your code? Your question currently is too abstract.

Comment: I will describe what I need.

Comment: Code is better than words.

Comment: I have edited my original question. PS.

Comment: Have you heard of inheritance?

Comment: Yes dear but the problem is different, I don't want any other stuff carried over from the parent class but just this property.

Comment: The last one calling Yuval 'dear' didn't survive ;)

Comment: inheritance will be answer for this. OrElse if need make it Class A as property of class B like (customer class having address class as a property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expecting something that isn't there. There is only one way to indicate that some property of `B` is 'the same' as that of `A`, and that is inheritance.

If you make `B` derive from `A`, it inherits the property `EmailID` and its annotations.

Another option is to use [annotations on interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5919567/993547), but those share the same problems as deriving in my opinion.

Else, you just have to copy/paste the annotation, since there isn't any obvious relationship except that they share the same name.

Comment: Yes I knew there is no such solution but I thought I should put my question... it was out of curiosity really.